# How to center data in table cells in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Is there any way to center the entries in the phpmyadmin column? I my case it much unreadable. I would center the entries in the `arrivaltime_id, route, stop_id`.

[image]

Comment: php admin is just a webpage, so you could use something like scriptMonkey to alter the layout

Answer (score 0):

A fix has been applied for the next release (4.5):
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/e7486480bbb93493fdacf0c86d9839a3626cdd90

It was decided, not to center but to add padding.